# How to create the Report Manager Website on a local machine in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am currently using SQL Server 2012 on my local machine and I would like to use SSRS (Reporting Services). However, I'm confused about the steps needed to create the Report Manager website! My understanding is that I need a URL like: //servername/Reports

Is the "servername" the same as my database instance name? If not, how do I create it? I just want the whole setup to be on my local machine so that I can test things and work offline. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "reporting services configuration manager" will tell you the URL in which to access the management website.  If it's installed it'll be in start->Microsoft SQL Server 2012->Configuration Tools.

When loaded select the option "Web Service URL" and it typically provides a hyperlink for access.

Having the whole setup is possible on your local machine, it just has to be setup from within the SQL Server installation process.